# I work in SCM/build. How do I tell non-programmers what I do?

Tags: version-control, build

Friends/family/etc ask me what I do and it always causes me pause while I think of how to explain it. They know what a software developer is but how can I explain what SCM is in 10 words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprising they know what a software developer does!

Anwyay, this sounds like a challenge for Haiku enthusiasts:

in 5-7-5 (I'm lazy when doing english haiku and my seasonal reference is flakey - try a 3-5-3 if you like)

```
from many good parts:
one programme on your PC;
lose track, get winter
```

(hmm, 13 words)

Answer (score 1):

I'd tell people "I work in software development".  I wouldn't bother explaining what you do IN software development unless they ask for more details.  I find that 90% of people are satisfied with that answer, and give more details to the 10% of people who are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The guy who makes sure that what gets deployed is what's meant to get deployed.